# Can't log into ubuntu 13.10 with correct password

Tags: 13.10, login-screen

I updated available packages just after the installation at first time in ubuntu 13.10.After the installations I restarted to finish the installations.The thing is, in the log in screen I put my correct password and then it goes back to the log in screen. I've tried so many times,but still the same.I can't log even as a guest user also

I followed some instructions to this that I found from some forums.

**method 1**

> Press CTRL+ALT+F1 and log in there and run:
>
> sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
>
> Then press CTRL+ALT+F7 and try to log in

this didn't work for me

**method 2**

> - Login as root ( Alt + Ctrl + F1 to get tty1)
> - chown youruser:youruser /home/youruser/.ICEauthority
>
>   make your youruse has full rights to the home directory
>     chown -R youruser:youruser /home/youruser

this is also not worked to me

note: I had removed mozilla thunderbird before getting updates from repositories(But I don't think that the root cause is there)

please help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problem with .Xauthority file.
You can try following.

```
Login as root (CTRL+ALT+F1)
chown youruser:youruser .Xauthority
chmod a+x .Xauthority
```

Comment: its not working :(

Comment: can you provide the content of your .xsession-errors file.